# How to reproduce ImageDataGenerator data

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, keras

I'm pretty new to Keras and used the ImageDataGenerator to train on images from a directory. I now want to predict unknown images in another directory but I'm not sure how to reproduce whatever transformations the code below is doing.

```
generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255).flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=16,
    class_mode='binary')
```

Is there a way to take an arbitrary numpy array or pil image and turn it into whatever this generator is producing? I realize I can trace the code and reproduce everything but that seems overly complex. It seems like there's probably some method or set of methods I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 0):

From the context, you may want to replace `train_data_dir` in your code with the `other_dir` you want to take images from.